# Cannot use USB presenter (Logitech, Flirc) when running Jack audio on a USB audio interface

Tags: usb, audio, bluetooth, usb-audio

I want to use a USB keyboard'ish device on a Pi 4 running Raspbian Buster. I tried both a Logitech R400 (radio based) device, and a Flirc programmble USB receiver for Infrared. Both work fine on a desktop linux computer.

They also work on the Pi, but as soon as I start the audio driver (jackd), the keys no longer work. Once I stop or kill `jackd`, the keys work again. I tried different USB connectors on the Pi. The sound interface is a generic USB device (Logilink UA0099).